# Sleep monitor without requiring password on KDE?

Tags: debian, kde, display-settings, screen-lock

I’ve got a Debian Stretch/KDE machine set up to run a CNC router. I'd like to set things up so that the display goes to sleep if the machine is left alone for a bit, but without requiring a password on wake. There seems to be no way to disable the `Require password after locking` setting, despite the Help alluding to a checkbox.

[image]

I just want the monitor to sleep to save energy (and not excessively wear the display), but I don’t want it to require a password on wake. Is that possible?

EDIT: It seems the monitor doesn’t actually sleep, it just leaves a lock screen up. Is sleeping not a part of KDE? Another post I found suggested I had to write a script to sleep the monitor after locking happened. I’m trying to avoid locking and just have sleep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dimming the display is part of the power management settings, no screen locker is implied, so you can disable the screen locker completely and still have you screen be dimmed after some inactivity.

Comment: Ah, silly me. I saw the screen locking settings and never thought to look elsewhere. A bit chagrined since macOS puts the setting in the same place (power management, not display settings).